# How to deploy Django code without restarting web server

Tags: python, django

I decided to move from PHP and start using Django. I have successfully installed Python and Django on my web server. How can I just code my Python/Django program, throw it to the server over FTP, and run it without the need to SSH to the server and restart the django server every time?

What is the method to run Django codes exactly the same way we run PHP code (having the server running all the time if possible)?

My server runs CentOS 5.8 and Apache.

Edit: 
Alright I really recommend this tutorial for who ever want to setup dJango on a web server , my recommendation after reading a lot of posts. Using dJango on Nginx web server is the most powerful performance you could get

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoAndNginx

Comment: This question is lacking necessary data such as what type of web server you are using, and how you are having it interpret the Python scripts (CGI, WSGI, mod_python, etc). In general, however, you should not need to start the Django server, but start your web server (which has been configured with a LocationMatch or similar command block) instead

Comment: This why I am asking the question because my info about the subject is not perfect !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't magically make Django run like PHP. Please look at the deployment documentation, as it's some of the best around.

[You'll see step by step instructions for apache.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/)

As for not having to SSH every time you load new code, the best tool for this job is `fabric`.

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/

Fabric is an amazing tool that is extremely easy to install and configure, which lets you run commands on your remote machine from your local machine.

For example, I simply type `fab production deploy` on my local machine to...

- push git changes
- pull git changes on remote
- run pip install
- migrate database
- run collectstatic
- finally "restart" apache - touching wsgi file.

I just want to stress that fabric is not like those deployment build scripts which are complicated. Fabric will literally take you 10 minutes to set up.